# SQLite - One liner/command Drop Table based on query of sqlite_master?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database called `HelpfulStats.sqlite3` which stores helpful stats about the days operation of the software it belongs to.
Inside `HelpfulStats.sqlite3` I have tables that follow a naming convention like so: `stats_YYMMDD`. During startup of the software, I check to see what the file size of `HelpfulStats.sqlite3` is and if it exceeds a set size threshold I call `VACUUM` on it, check to see if it's still too big, and then I run a query to delete the oldest `stats_` table if necessary.

I am successfully finding the oldest table by using `SELECT [tbl_name] FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND [tbl_name] LIKE 'stats_%' ORDER BY [tbl_name] ASC LIMIT 1`. However, **I can't seem to figure out how to pipe that SELECT result into a DROP TABLE command. Is it possible?**
I can *easily* just make them two separate queries, one to capture the result of the SELECT and then one to execute the DROP with that table name as a parameter but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it purely in one SQL execution.

I've tried things like `DROP TABLE (SELECT [tbl_name] FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND [tbl_name] LIKE 'stats_%' ORDER BY [tbl_name] ASC LIMIT 1)` but I get syntax errors on the first opening parenthesis. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: You're better off using a single table with a column that records the date instead of one table per day. Then it's just a simple `DELETE FROM stats WHERE date < '2019-03-15'` or whatever to clean it up.

Comment: That's a really good point though in my particular use case it makes more sense to group each day into a table. Or, I suppose I could make a catalog table to achieve what I'm looking for as well. Hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, SQLite does not support dynamic SQL queries, which is what you would need to do what you are attempting.  One workaround would be make your select call against `sqlite_master` from an app language (e.g. Java, Python, Node.js), and then build the delete query using code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I figured I'd have to do but just wanted to be sure there wasn't a *cleaner* way. Thanks again.